# Azure APIM - OpenApi: Format Integer not as String

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management the *CustomerId* is specified as an *integer* with an integer example value:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      type: object
      properties:
        CustomerId:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 100000
```

After saving, it changes to a string including a decimal separator:
**example: '100000.0'**

```
openapi: 3.0.1
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      type: object
      properties:
        CustomerId:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: '100000.0'
```

How can I specify integer example values?

Answer (score 1):

After I write Sample(Json) like the screenshot below, it automatically generate the Payload, and I export this api, I got the yaml file like this, can it help you?

```
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      type: object
      properties:
        CustomerId:
          type: integer
```

[image]

Comment: Two things. I need a long value, int64. And how does the value look after you reopen it?

Comment: As there's no example in the file, I got empty example after re-importing the api, and if I click `generate example`, I got data like this :https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsu5j.png

Comment: I think that is probably not support, see this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/data-types